# MySQL when a = 0, b = 0, but a <> b (binary)

Tags: mysql, datatypes, bitwise-comparison

Any idea of why this is so,

```
CREATE TABLE f AS
  SELECT b'000000001' AS a, x'01' AS b;
```

This creates two columns of

```
`a` varbinary(2) NOT NULL,
`b` varbinary(1) NOT NULL
```

However, when I run,

```
SELECT a=0, b=0, a=b, a<>b FROM f;
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| a=0 | b=0 | a=b | a<>b |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|   1 |   1 |   0 |    1 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

What's going on here? From the [docs on *The BINARY and VARBINARY Types*,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)

> **All bytes are significant in comparisons, including `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` operations.** `0x00` bytes and spaces are different in comparisons, with `0x00 < space`.

That explains why `a<>b`, but why does `a=0`, or `b=0` there?

Comment: I implemented a Elementary Cellular Automaton in PostgreSQL using the `bit(x)` type, and I wanted to do the same in MySQL. Essentially, I had to figure out the neighbors of each bit in question. Needless to say, it seemed almost impossible in MySQL.

Comment: And you were thinking of bit strings for each row in a 2D grid?  And use Boolean operations between rows, but something else for columns?  Less than 64 bits per row?  Consider `BIGINT UNSIGNED` and the shift operator `(1<<33)` gives you a bigint with bit#33 set, a la `b'000...010...0'`  `&`, `|`, etc. work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BINARY` is a misnomer.  It really refers to a string of bytes; it does not refer to binary numbers, and it isn't a unique datatype.

Also, `=` and `<>` adapt to the datatype(s) involved:

```
SELECT a=0, b=0,    -- numeric comparisons
       a=b, a<>b    -- BLOB comparisons; length matters
    FROM f;
```

It is a combination of the Operator and the Datatypes that controls what string vs numeric operations.

Some info on datatypes:

`BINARY` / `VARBINARY` / `BLOB` can be manipulated with "bit" operators `|` `&` `~` `^` -- not to be confused with logical operators `AND` (`&&`) and `OR` (`||`).  `BLOB`-like columns are used for non-character strings, such as images.  MySQL 8.0 stretches these operators beyond a 64-bit limit.  `INT` can also be manipulated with bit operators.

The `BIT(m)` datatype is prefixed with leading zeros if needed to fill out to full byte(s).  (Limit 64 bits.)  This datatype is almost never used.

`BINARY(1)` and `BINARY(22)` are 1- and 22-*byte* datatypes.  `CAST(1 AS BINARY(1)` converts the first `1` to a string `"1"`, then stuffs in hex 31 (ascii code for "1").  Try `SELECT HEX(CAST(1 AS binary(1))), HEX(CAST("1" AS BINARY(1)));` -- both yield `31`.

Comment: Wow, that's really distributing. If you update the answer to be explicit then that there are no **`Bit-Value Literals`**, there are just "`BINARY` type constructors", I'll accept this. The docs should be very clear about it though because some databases (like PostgreSQL really do have bit-value literals (using a `bit` type) that support sane bit-semantics. Good answer.

Comment: I don't feel like I understand how the `bit datatype` works, could you explain the definition of `datatype` here, versus constructor for a binary datatype? Perhaps explaining this, `SELECT CAST(1 AS binary(1))` versus `SELECT x'01';`

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I added more.  It is messy and confusing.  And the manual sometimes does not have enough info to clarify things.  I find `HEX()` as the best way to extract the truth, at least from what is stored in a table.

Answer (score 2):

**it is no warranty** - which part of  **x = y** would be converted with auto type convertion

```
SELECT
    a = 0,
    a = cast( 0 AS BINARY ),
    cast(a as SIGNED),
    cast(a as SIGNED) = 0,
    b,
    b = 0,
    b = cast( 0 AS BINARY ),
    cast(b as SIGNED),
    b = cast(b as SIGNED) = 0,
    a = b,
    a <> b 
FROM
    f;
```

this is give You more information